# A counting question about pairs of three-digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

the question asks how many pairs of $3$ digit numbers exist such that when one is added to the other, we never have to use a "carry-over". For clarification, a carry-over occurs  when you add $75 + 68$, because $5 + 8=13$, which contributes the "$1$" to the next round of addition "$7+6$". Note that you need to have another carry-over because $7 + 6 + 1=14$. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: How far have you gotten with this?

Comment: Hi I first ranked the three digit numbers from small to large. I could see that this discussion is about three digit numbers from 100 to 899. Then I tried to generalize something for different numbers, but I felt it is a lot of work since it is very depending on the numbers on each individual digit for different numbers.

Comment: This does seem like a laborious approach.  Look at the hints in Lane's answer for a better idea.  Also, in future please show what you have tried in the body of your question.  It will help prevent your posts from being closed.

Comment: Do $111+222$ and $222+111$ count as one pair or two? (I.e., does the order of the two three-digit numbers in an allowable pair matter or not?)

Comment: I suppose the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I am understanding the question correctly, we are trying to find the number of non-ordered pairs $\{\overline{abc}, \overline{def}\}$ such that $\overline{abc} + \overline{def}$ does not require a "carry-over."

I will not give away the specifics of the solution so you can try things out on your own. My general recommendation is to look at the digits separately and count the number of combination possible for $\{c,f\}, \{b,e\}, \{a,d\}$. Note that $\{c,f\}$ and $\{b,e\}$ should have the same number of possible combinations (whereas $\{a,d\}$ is slightly different given that none of them can be $0$). Also note that to not have a "carry-over" when adding two digits means the sum of the two digits should be less than 10 (i.e. less than or equal to 9).

Multiplying the number of combinations for each digit gives you the total number of combinations. In addition, we need to handle the double-counted pairs. In this case, dividing by $2$ should suffice since addition is symmetrical.

Edit: oops sorry yah the comment below is right haha, do pick out those when doubled also don’t cause any carry-overs, also fixing typo on $\leq 9$

Comment: The correction for double-counting needs to be slightly more clever than dividing by $2$, since we also have equal pairs such as $\{123,123\}$, which are not double-counted.

Comment: Hello! This is really a new and clever perspective and I didn't even think in this way! Thanks very much for your suggestion and I will try in this way. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you mean less than or equal to $9$?